# Sumar horas en php ("en formato 24:00")

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hola gente estoy a la deriva con un problema, que no le pudo encontrar la vuelta, a ver si alguno me puede dar una mano.
Estoy haciendo un script que suma horas que traigo por base, y fracciona cada 30 minutos, el problema es que cuando supero las 24:00 en vez de obtener 01:00 que seria el día siguiente, obtengo 25:00. Copio el script para ver si alguno puede darme una mano. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
/*Hora desde*/
    $start=strtotime($init_hora); 

/*Ultima hora*/
    $end=strtotime($fin_hora);

if($start >= $end){
     $end = strtotime ( '+24 hour' , strtotime ($fin_hora) ) ;
}

for ($i=$start; $i<=$end ;$i = strtotime ('+30 minute',$i))
{

    $data[]= array(
        'dia_calendario' => $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day, 
        'hora_reserva' => date('H:i:s',$i), 
        'comentario_reserva' => '', 
        'estado' => 'libre',
        'espacio_id'=>$espacio_id
    );

}
```